# How to split lines from CSV file in a Flutter web app

Tags: csv, flutter-web, filepicker

I am trying to make an import option of data from a CSV file but I have an issue with a field which contains "\n" character inside it.

This is how I pick the file when the user clicks the import button:

```
FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
        withData: true,
        type: FileType.custom,
        allowedExtensions: ["csv"],
      ).then(
        (value) => (value != null)
            ? _confirmImport(
                context,
                value: value.files.single.bytes,
              )
            : null,
      );
```

Afterwards I split the lines using:

```
String.fromCharCodes(file!).split("\n");
```

How can I split the line and also keep "\n", inside that field?
Or, alternatively, how can I detect "\n" inside the fields and remove them, without removing the "\n" at the end of the line?

How it says in the subject, this is for Flutter web app.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar situation using a trimRight().split('\n')